# How to dynamically omit gradient paths from backprop in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to do beam search along some sequence and then apply loss function to the result. Result of the beam search incorporates only a part of tensors I had to evaluate during beam searching, but Tensorflow has to store all of them in the memory, because it can't predict whether they'll be still relevant at the end of searching. This consumes a lot of memory and results in OOM.

I know there is a `tf.stop_gradient` function, but it is static and I'm looking for dynamic mechanism which would allow me to evict no longer needed tensor values from memory.